# operator keyword with dynamic type in c#

Tags: asp.net, .net, c#-4.0, visual-studio-2017, dynamictype

I am using a dynamic type for json response

```
{
    "liveTrackingAvailable": "false",
    "maxSeatsPerTicket": "6",
    "nonAC": "true",
    "operator": "25541201",
    "otgEnabled": "true",
}
```

my code seems like in _result I have stored the json

```
  var result = new Result
  {
    LiveTrackingAvailable = _result.liveTrackingAvailable,
    MaxSeatsPerTicket = _result.maxSeatsPerTicket,
    IsDropPointMandatory = _result.nonAC,
    Operator = _result.operator
  }
```

But I am unable to read last line because dynamic is taking operator as a keyword.

Comment: `@` is used to escape reserved keywords, but I am not sure if thats helpful here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
  var result = new Result
  {
     LiveTrackingAvailable = _result.liveTrackingAvailable,
     MaxSeatsPerTicket = _result.maxSeatsPerTicket,
     IsDropPointMandatory = _result.nonAC,
     Operator = _result.@operator
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try generating `C#` class from the json structure from this site: http://json2csharp.com/

This will generate the following class:

```
public class RootObject
{
    public string liveTrackingAvailable { get; set; }
    public string maxSeatsPerTicket { get; set; }
    public string nonAC { get; set; }
    public string @operator { get; set; }
    public string otgEnabled { get; set; }
}
```

See if this approach helps.